# Flash Builder for a Flash project: Workspace

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

Do I have to create a new workspace for every new .fla (Flash project) in Flash Builder, or can I reuse the workspace folder for multiple .fla projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse the same workspace and just create a new flash project through File->New->(Whichever project type you like)

Comment: You may also create working sets like in eclipse if you want to group specific flash projects together to keep it organized

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the same workspace, however, the larger the set of projects get, the slower your automatic builds will be. You can close unused projects to reduce these times, or create workspaces that group related projects.